# make target with multiple extension

Tags: makefile

How to do the following in gnu make (on mac). I have files with extendion `.js` and `.jsx` which needs to go through the build.

```
SRC = $(shell find src -name '*.js' -o -name '*.jsx')
LIB = $(SRC:src/%=lib/%)
lib/%.js: src/%.js
    @echo "building $@"
```

above only define the target for `*.js` files. Now, to include *.jsx, I duplicated like below (which works).

```
lib/%.js: src/%.js
    @echo "building $@"

lib/%.jsx: src/%.jsx
    @echo "building $@"
```

Anyway to combine these. I tried like

```
lib/%.js%: src/%.js%
    @echo "building $@"
```

but didn't work (`make: *** No rule to make target`lib/abc.jsx', needed by `build'.  Stop.`)

### EDIT:

duplicating the build for `js & jsx` didn't give the same result as it causes duplication of files. The build process compile `jsx` file and write as `.js`. so, what I am trying to express is, `for all files with extension`.js or .jsx`, run it through the build process (which renames the compiled output as .js for both js and jsx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a static pattern. Also make has a builtin `wildcard` function for simple file expansion

```
SRC := $(wildcard src/*.js src/*.jsx)
LIB := $(SRC:src/%=lib/%)

$(LIB): lib/%: src/%
    @echo building $@ from $^
```

Comment: `wildcard` isn't recursive, while `shell find` is